# Can safe wallet interact with smart contracts?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have set up a safe multi-sig wallet for my protocol treasury and governance. We the multi-sig wallet to be the owner and deployer of the protocol factory smart contracts. Is that possible and how can you do that?

Follow-up question: we have added the option in the factory smart contract to add a protocol fee that can be set and activated by the owner, which in this case would be a safe wallet. Can the safe wallet interact with the smart contract methods and set and activate the fee? Key thing is that the safe wallet(multi-sig) would have several owners and would need several signatures to approve transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the safe wallet can interact with the smart contracts. For that, head over to safe wallet, and you'll see this `new transaction` button, clicking on that, you'll see this interface.

[image]

**Click on transaction builder and**
**Paste the contract address**
[image]

**Scroll down and you'll see the methods to call, select whatever function you wanna call, pass the arguments, and click on add transaction.**
[image]

After that, you can create multiple transactions and execute all of them at once. You can also execute a single transaction

Comment: Thank you for explaining!